# Sliding is not working in IE . But it works fine in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke

Hi I am working on dotnetnuke. I have developed a module that slides images. Sliding is not working in IE but it woks fine in all other browsers. How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function () {

$('#da-slider').cslider();

    });

</script>.
```

Images are not sliding , but all the text are overlapping in the same image.

Comment: js errors???? use IE debug tool

Comment: you can check the javascript error in Developer tool(F12) > Console tab. If you want to debug the javascript you can use Script tab > click on "Start debuging" button

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'getScript': object is null or undefined 
initWidgets.js, line 6 character 9
SCRIPT5007: Object expected 
Test.aspx, line 740 character 9 I am getting above 2 errors

Answer (score 0):

`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'getScript': object is null or undefined initWidgets.js, line 6 character 9 SCRIPT5007: Object expected Test.aspx, line 740 character 9`

If you are not using skin widgets, you can disable them from Admin > Site Settings.

It will be helpful if you can post url or all of your errors but most of the time, due to nature of how javascript code executes in browser, you need to fix all of the errors related to javascript.